# c# mainui drops behind other windows, issue with topmost

Tags: c#, topmost

I have a problem with topmost level, found a solution that "works" but it don't look so nice. Is there another "cleaner" way to solve this?
Here's my code: comments of event in code.

```
    OrderTemplateView template;
private void toolStripButton4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (template != null)
        {
            template.Close(); //must close to trigger close event.
            template.Dispose();
        }
        mainUi.TopMost = true; // must set my mainUi topMost here othervise it drops in the background of other windows open at the computer.
        template = new OrderTemplateView(this);
        template.TopMost = true;// must set my dialog topmost othervise it drops behind my mainUi
        template.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
        mainUi.TopMost = false;//must release my topmost so other windows on the computer can be called to front.
        template.TopMost = false;
        template.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Updated code that does the same job:

```
 private void toolStripButton4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (template != null)
        {
            template.Close();
            template.Dispose();
        }
        template = new OrderTemplateView(mainUi);
        template.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
        template.ShowDialog(mainUi);
    }
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Rather than setting TopMost, try the following:

1. Remove all your references to `TopMost`
2. Call `mainUi.BringToFront()`
3. Call `template.ShowDialog(mainUi)`, noting that the parent control is passed to the dialog.

Comment: Remove all your references to `TopMost`, then call `mainUi.BringToFront()`, then call `template.ShowDialog(mainUi)` - note I'm passing mainUi to the call to ShowDialog().

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14089033)

Comment: @pylover I've updated the answer to be a proper answer.  Cheers for the correction.

Comment: After all of formatting optimizations, Please remind: your answer is too short, could you explain what is happening and how this workaround is working?

Comment: Perfect. does the same job as my topMost. Had to change something in my MainUi so my subform is accessible.The code now looks much more fluent :D

Comment: @pylover The answer is succinct, correct, and fairly self-explanatory.  If the OP wishes to learn more about why this works, then they can research BringToFront() and ShowDialog() themselves.